# how to manually expand a submenu in a shiny dashboard side bar

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to manually expand a submenu in a sidebar in shiny dashboard. The `updateTabItems` function only works with normal menus, but not with nested menus.

Here is basic example (modified from the `updateTabItems` documentation) to show the problem. If I clicked on 'Switch tab', it switches the menus, but it doesn't expand the first menu that has a submenu. It seems that it only selected the submenu but doesn't expand the tree.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),
        menuSubItem("Sub Menu 1",icon = icon("folder-open"), tabName = "subMenu1")
      ),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    ),
    actionButton('switchtab', 'Switch tab')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        h2("Dashboard tab content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
        h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$switchtab, {
    newtab <- switch(input$tabs,
      "subMenu1" = "widgets",
      "widgets" = "subMenu1"
    )
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", newtab)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

I would like manually expand the tree, select the menu and the submenu. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

**Update:**

A working code with the complete solution is in [Shiny expanding submenu items manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847838/shiny-expanding-submenu-items-manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped myself out defining some JavaScript, using the JavaScript interface `extendShinyjs` in shiny:

```
js$selectMenuItem(0)
js$selectMenuSubItem(2)

useShinyjs(), 
extendShinyjs(text = jsSelectMenuItem), 
extendShinyjs(text = jsSelectMenuSubItem)
```

## select menuItem i

```
jsSelectMenuItem <- "shinyjs.selectMenuItem = function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.treeview > a').eq(i).click();
    }, 200);
}"
```

## select menuSubItem i

```
jsSelectMenuSubItem <- "shinyjs.selectMenuSubItem = function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.treeview-menu > li > a').eq(i).click();
    }, 800);
}"
```

Comment: Thank for you solution. Eventually I found a way to do that using the shinyjs 
        `shinyjs::delay(100, shinyjs::addClass("admin","active"))` whre "admin" is the id of the menu.

Comment: @Geovany what exactly do you mean with id of the menu? MenuItems and MenuSubItems do not have IDs, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @marcopah I was talking about the `menuItemOutput` function that allows you to create the menu on the server side. In that function the only parameter is the `utputId`.